# Creating Objects in Iterator with React.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, iterator, components

I have an array

```
let ability = ["100", "500" , "90" , "90" , "90" , "90" , "90" , "90" , "90" , "90"]
```

I'm creating objects in an iterator and want to pass each value of the array to through the props of "Progress Circle". So the width of the first object is 100 the width of the second is 500 and so on.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ProgressCircle from './ProgressCircle';
import './App.css';

class Skills extends Component {

render(){
let skills = ["HTML", "CSS", "Swift", "PHP", "Python", "React.js", 
"Javascript", "Git", "API Integration", "Java"]
let ability = ["100", "500" , "90" , "90" , "90" , "90" , "90" , "90" , 
"90" , "90"]
let map = skills.map(function(skill, i) {
  return(
    <div key={i}>
      <h1 id="skill">{skill}</h1>
      <ProgressCircle ability={ability[i]}/>
    </div>
  );
 })
 return(
  <div className="skillsCont">
    <h1 id="skillsTitle">My Skills</h1>
    {map}
  </div>
   );
 }
 }
 export default Skills;
```

However when the objects are rendered in the object's class the value passed in the props is not unique. It keeps changing for ALL objects as the iterator goes through the array so all the objects end up having the props of the last value in the array i.e. the width of all the objects end up being 90

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import $ from 'jquery';
import './App.css';

class ProgressCircle extends Component {
componentDidMount() {
$('.enter').click(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.progressFill').animate({"width": this.props.ability}, 1000);
  }.bind(this), 6000);
}.bind(this));
}
render(){
return(
  <div className="progress">
    <div className="progressFill">
    </div>
  </div>
);
} 
}

export default ProgressCircle;
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you are selecting **ALL** elements with the `$('.progressFill').animate` and therefore, when the last one runs, it will change every element with the progressFill class.

You should use [ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) to select only the element that your `ProgressCircle` is creating:

```
import React, {
    Component
} from 'react';
import $ from 'jquery';
import './App.css';

class ProgressCircle extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        // create a ref to store the textInput DOM element
        this.progressFillRef = React.createRef();
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        $('.enter').click(function() {
            setTimeout(function() {
                $(this.progressFillRef.current).animate({
                    "width": this.props.ability
                }, 1000);
            }.bind(this), 6000);
        }.bind(this));
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className = "progress" >
                <div className = "progressFill"ref = {this.progressFillRef} >
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default ProgressCircle;
```

So, you should create a reference on your component's constructor, and then use that reference on your `<div>`. When your js runs to do the annimation, you can get the actual rendered`<div>` with `this.myRefThatIHaveCreated.current`, and then pass it to the `$` selector

Comment: To make the annimation work you should use the ref feature of react. Will add an example to the answer

Comment: Nice! So, could you please mark my answer as correct, please? :)

Comment: Hi @StephenThomas if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

For brevity, I replaced your Progress with a material UI component to show a nice setup that funtions perfectly without jQuery.

Other important thing is to keep stuff that doesn't change out of the render method to improve performance.

The getPercentage function is added just because the material-ui component expects a value from 0-100. If you want to use a linear progress indicator, you'll also need a relative value - with an absolute width value, you'd run into lots of weird lines handing out of the screen :)

And I got rid of the id prop. The unique selector in react is key, for styles use className.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import CircularProgress from '@material-ui/core/CircularProgress';
import './App.css';

const skills = [
    "HTML", "CSS", "Swift", "PHP", "Python", "React.js", "Javascript", "Git", "API Integration", "Java"
]
const ability = [
    100, 500, 90, 90, 90, 90, 90 , 90 , 90 , 90
]

const abilityMax = 1000

export function getPercentage (index) {
    const value = ability[i]
    const percentageOfMax = value / abilityMax
    return percentageOfMax * 100
}

class Skills extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.renderItems = this.renderItems.bind(this);
    }

    renderItems(skills) {
        return(
            skills.map((skill, i) => 
                <div key={i}>
                    <h1>{skill}</h1>
                    <CircularProgress
                        variant="determinate"
                        value={getPercentage(i)}
                    />
                </div>
            )
        )
    }

    render() {
        return (
                <div className="skillsCont">
                    <h1>My Skills</h1>
                    {this.renderItems(skills)}
                </div>
            ) 
    }
}

export default Skills;
```

Hope that helps!